# Automatic logout when typing password

Tags: logout

I think it may be due the graphic card driver I installed. Is there anyway I can get in through a back door to the admin so I can uninstall the driver?

Answer (score 0):

well you can enter.
while your system is in booting at GRUB menu choose Restore option.Then in the next step you'll get some options and there choose drop to root shell. There you are as admin and you can do there.

But Be careful with what ever you are doing. don't touch any unless you dont know clearly.

Hope that helps.